# AWS S3 web site with custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I've successly deployed and application on AWS S3 with [@ng-toolkit/serverless](http://@ng-toolkit/serverless%20-%20npm)  on the AWS generated endpoint. Now I want to use a custom domain I've purchased, in order to access the app from i.e. mydomain.com

Following the [AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) I have to modify the policy bucket with the following JSON (I used mydomain.com):

```
{ "Version":"2012-10-17", 
  "Statement":[
   { 
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::mydomain.com/*"]
   }] 
}
```

The problem is that when I save I got error with "Access denied" message.

I used both root user and generated secondary user (as AWS suggests) with AdministratorAccess permissions, but I'm unable to save the policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to lock yourself out of a bucket with a bad policy (not sure if that applies to your case?). If so you can try the below CLI command (using the root users API key) to remove any existing bucket policy:

`aws s3api delete-bucket-policy --bucket mydomain.com`

If this is your issue, you should be able to insert a new bucket policy as normal now.

Comment: I tried your command @MisterSmith but unfortunately didn't resolve my problem. Finally I get the solution changing the setting inside Permissions -> Public access setting -> Manage public bucket policies -> Block new public bucket policies  = false. Doing this I'm enable to save the policy.

Answer (score 0):

If could help someone I finally get the solution changing the setting of the S3 bucket in Permissions -> Public access setting -> Manage public bucket policies -> Block new public bucket policies = false. 
Doing this I'm able to save the policy!